# Reasons for strange heart rate graph following exercise (line going up and down)?

Tags: homework, cardiology

Following a 2 minute general jumping and movement exercise designed to involve the entire body, the pulse was taken every minute for ten seconds. Strangely, the graph appears to jump up and down, for which I have little understanding why.

The pulse was measured simply and crudely with the traditional "fingers on the wrist" method.

If it is not clear, time is on the x axis and no. of heartbeats per minute on the y.
[image: Time vs pulse]

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the graph were what I would consider to be "normal", the general motion of the line should be downwards, settling to the normal heart rate. Instead, the graph has decided to jump up and down yet there should be no or little error.

Comment: A possible answer to this question could be user AliceD's suggestion in the chat room that "If sampling rate is low, you get this jumpy behavior because variations result in these 'binary' jumps."

Comment: Given the manual way the heart rate was determined I question the accuracy of the data. I would suggest to repeat the experiment and check repeatability of the data. Accuracy can be increased by determining the pulse heart rate over a longer interval than 10 seconds.